# How to calculate the SUM of rows values for one column of a table created using TCPDF?

Tags: php, html, sql, codeigniter, tcpdf

Please could you help me to **calculate and display the SUM VALUE** of the rows of a column named "prime" in my table which is created in a PDF report using **TCPDF** (the data is being extracted from my database).
Thank you in advance. I would be very grateful if you could help me.
[A better description of my result table in this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRI9y.png)
The main part of my code is this:

```
    <?php
set_time_limit(0);
tcpdf();


 // create new PDF document
$pdf = new TCPDF('L', PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

// remove default header/footer
$pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
$pdf->setPrintFooter(false);

// set default monospaced font
//$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

// set margins
//$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);

// set auto page breaks
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

// set image scale factor
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

// set some language dependent data:
$lg = Array();
$lg['a_meta_charset'] = 'UTF-8';
$lg['a_meta_dir'] = 'rtl';
$lg['a_meta_language'] = 'fa';
$lg['w_page'] = 'page';

// set some language-dependent strings (optional)
$pdf->setLanguageArray($lg);

// ---------------------------------------------------------



// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();


$pdf->SetXY(16, 10);


// set document information
$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
//$pdf->SetAuthor('Nicola Asuni');
//$pdf->SetSubject('TCPDF Tutorial');
//$pdf->SetKeywords('TCPDF, PDF, example, navettes, guide');
// set default header data
//$pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE.'', PDF_HEADER_STRING);
 $pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
// set header and footer fonts
$pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
$pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));



$pdf->setRTL(true);

$pdf->SetFont('xzar', '', 10);

    $sql= "SELECT * FROM nav_agent WHERE matricule='$mat'";  
    $query = $this->db->query($sql); 


$saut=0;
$tbl = '<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" border="1">
   <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="border: 1px double #000000; text-align:center;"  colspan="2">الإذن </th>
            <th style="border: 1px double #000000; text-align:center;"  colspan="2">التنقل</th>
            <th style="border: 1px double #000000; text-align:center;"  colspan="2">التوقيت</th>
            <th style="border: 1px double #000000; text-align:center;"  colspan="4"> </th>
       </tr>


<tr>
<td style="border: 1px double #000000; text-align:center;">العدد</td>  
<td style="border: 1px double #000000; text-align:center;">التاريخ</td>  
<td style="border: 1px double #000000; text-align:center;">من</td>  
<td style="border: 1px double #000000; text-align:center;">إلى</td>  
<td style="border: 1px double #000000; text-align:center;">الإنطلاق</td>  
<td style="border: 1px double #000000; text-align:center;">الرجوع</td>  
<td style="border: 1px double #000000; text-align:center;">المدة المقضاة (بالساعة)</td>  
<td style="border: 1px double #000000; text-align:center;"> مبلغ منحة التنقل </td> 
<td style="border: 1px double #000000; text-align:center;">رقم السيارة</td>
</tr>
';

$prime=0;
foreach ($query->result() as $row){

 $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM fiche_nav WHERE id_navette='$row->id_navette'";  


  $query1 = $this->db->query($sql1);    
foreach ($query1->result() as $row1){


$delai = strtotime($row1->heureret) - strtotime($row1->heuredep); 
$time_h = ($delai/60)/60; 


if ($val_grade == 'A1' or   $val_grade == 'A2')
    $montant1 = 15.000;
    else
        if ($val_grade == 'A3' or   $val_grade == 'B'  
         or     $val_grade =='ouv cat 8' or $val_grade =='ouv cat 9' or $val_grade =='ouv cat 10')  


    $montant1 = 9.000;
    else
        if ($val_grade == 'C' or    $val_grade == 'D'  
         or     $val_grade =='ouv cat 1' or $val_grade =='ouv cat 2' or $val_grade =='ouv cat 3'    
         or $val_grade =='ouv cat 4' or $val_grade =='ouv cat 5' or $val_grade =='ouv cat 6' or $val_grade =='ouv cat 7')

    $montant1 = 6.750;   


if ($val_grade == 'A1' or   $val_grade == 'A2')
    $montant2 = 35.000;
    else
        if ($val_grade == 'A3' or   $val_grade == 'B'  
         or     $val_grade =='ouv cat 8' or $val_grade =='ouv cat 9' or $val_grade =='ouv cat 10')  


    $montant2 = 25.000;
    else
        if ($val_grade == 'C' or    $val_grade == 'D'  
         or     $val_grade =='ouv cat 1' or $val_grade =='ouv cat 2' or $val_grade =='ouv cat 3'    
         or $val_grade =='ouv cat 4' or $val_grade =='ouv cat 5' or $val_grade =='ouv cat 6' or $val_grade =='ouv cat 7')

    $montant2 = 18.000;


if ( $time_h <= 7 )
$prime = 0;
else

    if ( $time_h >7 && $time_h <= 14 ) 
$prime = 0.5 * $montant1;

else


    if ( $time_h >14 && $time_h < 24 )
$prime = $montant1; 


else


    if ( $time_h >=24 ) 
$prime = $montant2;     

$tbl=$tbl. '<tr>
<td style="border: 0px solid #000000; text-align:center"></td>
<td style="border: 0px solid #000000; text-align:center">'. $row1->datedep .'</td>
<td style="border: 0px solid #000000; text-align:center">'. $row1->lieudep .'</td>
<td style="border: 0px solid #000000; text-align:center">'. $row1->destination .'</td>
<td style="border: 0px solid #000000; text-align:center">'. $row1->heuredep .'</td>
<td style="border: 0px solid #000000; text-align:center">'. $row1->heureret .'</td>
<td style="border: 0px solid #000000; text-align:center">'. $time_h .'</td>
<td style="border: 0px solid #000000; text-align:center">'. $prime .'</td>
<td style="border: 0px solid #000000; text-align:center;"> '.$row1->matriculevoiture .' </td>

<td style="border: 0px solid #000000; text-align:center"></td>
<td style="border: 0px solid #000000; text-align:center"></td>
<td style="border: 0px solid #000000; text-align:center"></td>
<td style="border: 0px solid #000000; text-align:center"></td>
<td style="border: 0px solid #000000; text-align:center"></td>
</tr>
' ;

}


}

$tbl=$tbl.' </thead></table> ';


$pdf->writeHTML($tbl, true, false, false, false, '');


  // WHAT SHALL I ADD HERE TO CALCULATE the TOTAL VALUE i.e SUM OF "$PRIME" ROWS?

// close and output PDF document
 $date_auj=date('dmY',NOW());
    $strr = "Rapport-".$date_auj.".pdf";
$pdf->Output($strr, 'I');
//ob_end_clean(); 
//$pdf->Output($strr, 'I');

//============================================================+
// END OF FILE
//============================================================+
?>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear at all. What column do you want the sum of? Consider [edit]ing your question so just the code needed to show the problem. Hint, if what you are trying to sum is in your `foreach` loop do the addition in that loop and use the result where you need it. Also take a look at how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thank you so much. The column is named : مبلغ منحة التنقل , and each row of this same column displays a different value of the field I named "$prime". I just want to add (a for loop?) at the end of my script to calculate all the displayed values of "$prime". I edited my question above by adding an image which explains better my table and what i m trying to calculate. (please see the link).

Comment: Have you tried solving these two problems step by step? If your SQL query returns inproper data, there is no connection to the PDF library. And if the query returns proper data, but your PDF does not contain it, there is no connection to SQL after all

Answer (score 0):

you can declare a variable before `$prime` variable

```
$grandPrime=0;
$prime=0;
foreach ($query->result() as $row){
```

initialize it here

```
$grandPrime+=$prime;
$tbl=$tbl. '<tr>
<td style="border: 0px solid #000000; text-align:center"></td>
<td style="border: 0px solid #000000; text-align:center">'. $row1->datedep .'</td>
```

and use it after your loop end.

Comment: Thank you dear Mahmood ! Indeed, $grandPrime was missing. I resolved the problem by adding it.
$grandPrime=0;
$prime=0;
foreach ($query->result() as $row){
//MY IF CONDITIONS etc
 $grandPrime+=$prime;
$tbl=$tbl. '<tr>
//MY TABLE CONTENT..etc.
</tr>
' ;
}
$pdf->writeHTML($tbl, true, false, false, false, '');
// THEN I ADDED A FOR LOOP TO DISPLAY grandPRIME VALUE
      $num_prime = count($prime);
      for($i = 0; $i < $num_prime; ++$i) 
   {   $pdf->SetFont('xzar', 'B', 11); 
          $pdf->Cell(277,5,  "   المبلغ الجملي    $grandPrime    ",1,0,'C'); }

Comment: @Miss_w i'm glad to hear that, if my answer helped you somewhere kindly mark this as a accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

After the line

```
$prime=0;
```

Add another var let’s name it `$sumPrimes`

```
$sumPrimes =0;
```

And after your last else when you assign your `$prime`:

```
else
    if ( $time_h >=24 ) 
$prime = $montant2;
```

You could calculate the sum like that:

```
$sumPrimes += $prime;
```

After your foreach and before you close the table:

```
$tbl=$tbl.' </thead></table> ';
```

You can print the `$sumPrimes.`

Comment: Thank you dear Abdello! Indeed, a sum variable was missing. I resolved the problem by adding it. $grandPrime=0; $prime=0; foreach ($query->result() as $row){ //MY IF CONDITIONS etc $grandPrime+=$prime; $tbl=$tbl. '<tr> //MY TABLE CONTENT..etc. </tr> ' ; } $pdf->writeHTML($tbl, true, false, false, false, ''); // THEN I ADDED A FOR LOOP TO DISPLAY grandPRIME VALUE $num_prime = count($prime); for($i = 0; $i < $num_prime; ++$i) { $pdf->SetFont('xzar', 'B', 11); $pdf->Cell(277,5, " المبلغ الجملي $grandPrime ",1,0,'C'); }

Comment: @Miss_w i'm glad to hear that, if my answer helped you somewhere kindly mark this as a accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you dear members for you precious help! Indeed, another sum variable was missing.
I resolved the problem by adding it as shown below:

```
$grandPrime=0; $prime=0; 

foreach ($query->result() as $row)
```

`{` //MY IF CONDITIONS TO CALCULATE THE VALUE OF PRIME etc ..

```
$grandPrime+=$prime; 

$tbl=$tbl. '<tr>
```

//MY TABLE CONTENT..etc.

```
</tr> ' ; } 
$pdf->writeHTML($tbl, true, false, false, false, '');
```

// THEN I ADDED A FOR LOOP TO DISPLAY grandPRIME VALUE, where $num_prime is simply the number of prime rows

```
$num_prime = count($prime);
 for($i = 0; $i < $num_prime; ++$i) 
{ $pdf->SetFont('xzar', 'B', 11);
 $pdf->Cell(277,5, " المبلغ الجملي $grandPrime ",1,0,'C'); 
}
```

This is the correct result I finally obtained: [Please clic the link to see the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyexY.png)

THANK YOU AGAIN :)) YOU REALLY HELPED ME !